# Find difference in quantity column of two tables

Tags: sql

Suppose I have two tables, with a item name and quantity:

Table 1

| Item Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| a | 10 |
| b | 15 |
| c | 2 |

Table 2

| Item Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| a | 45 |
| b | 2 |

I want to find the difference in quantity of items from both tables e.g. table 2 - table 1

| Item Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| a | 35 |
| b | -13 |
| c | -2 |

I already have code to get the appropriate data from each table, I'm just struggling to apply the difference:

```
SELECT ???INV2-INV1??? From

(SELECT `Item Name` as Name1, SUM(`Quantity`) AS TotalQuantity
FROM  `table1` 
GROUP BY `Item Name`) INV1,

(SELECT `Item Name` as Name1, SUM(`Quantity`) AS TotalQuantity
FROM  `table2` 
GROUP BY `Item Name`) INV2;
```

How can I find the difference between `INV1` and `INV2`? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to get all the rows of the 2 tables (with negative quantities for `table1`) and then aggregate:

```
SELECT `Item Name`, SUM(Quantity) total_Quantity
FROM (
  SELECT `Item Name`, Quantity FROM table2 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `Item Name`, -Quantity FROM table1
) t
GROUP BY `Item Name`
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0bbd6a876a105ea9f85760dfdfcd9ff7).
Resuts:

| Item Name | total_Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| a | 35 |
| b | -13 |
| c | -2 |

Answer (score 2):

Give the values aliases and subtract:

```
SELECT Inv1.Name1, Inv1.TotalQuantity - inv2.TotalQuantity
FROM (SELECT `Item Name` as Name1, SUM(`Quantity`) AS TotalQuantity
      FROM  `table1` 
      GROUP BY `Item Name`
     ) INV1 JOIN
     (SELECT `Item Name` as Name1, SUM(`Quantity`) AS TotalQuantity
      FROM  `table2` 
      GROUP BY `Item Name`
     ) INV2
     ON inv1.Name1  = inv2.Name1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way:

```
sqlite> select * from t1;
1|a|10
2|b|5
sqlite> select * from t2;
1|a|2
2|b|6
sqlite> select x.name,x.quantity - y.quantity from t1 x, t2 y where x.name = y.name;
a|8
b|-1
sqlite>
```

You probably want to do an `INNER JOIN` for more robustness though.